# How to do advanced list modelling and matching in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, data-modeling, database

I'm building a university course search application and my data contains a pre-requisites field I need to match.

It looks like this: "Any English, Chemistry, Methods or Specialist Maths"

If I was doing it with a raw Python structure, I'd do a list with first level being AND and second level lists being OR, in this case:
`[["English", "Literature", "Language"],["Chemistry"],["Methods","Specialist Maths"]]`
which is how I'd say this case needs an English AND Chemistry AND (Methods OR Specialist).

Then with Python I'd just iterate over it and check to see if the conditions are satisfied.

So how, with data like this and a bunch of input subjects, can I use MongoDB queries to check if a course is suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking to do is too complicated for the normal query operators.  So you will need to use the [$where operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/) which can execute arbitrary JavaScript in a query.  It comes with caveats and limitations, so it could be very slow if it needs to check a lot of matching permutations.

One suggestion that could
 help is to create a separate collection where the documents are your individual OR lists of pre-requisites.  This collection would represent all the pre-requisites of all the classes.  For example:

```
{_id: ObjectId("50fe0f437f774e8013000001"), 
    prereq: ["English", "Literature", "Language"]},
{_id: ObjectId("50fe0f437f774e8013000002"), 
    prereq: ["Chemistry"]},
{_id: ObjectId("50fe0f437f774e8013000003"), 
    prereq: ["Methods","Specialist Maths"]},
...
```

The courses themselves would point to the ObjectId's of the pre-requisites instead of the actual values.  The query would then be in two steps.  First find all the pre-requisites that match the input subjects.

```
db.preReqCollection.find({prereq: {$in: inputSubjectList}) 
==> matchingPreReqList (the List of ObjectIds from preReqCollection met by inputSubjectList)
```

Then use a simpler `$where operator` query to check if course pre-requisites are in in the `matchingPreReqList`.

Comment: Hmmm... I like this. Thanks for the help!